# poetry not install pyqt5-plugins

Tags: python-poetry

my first problem, did not install pyqt-tools, because current version pyqt-tools dependents pyqt5 version 5.15.4. Ok. I install this version and retray install pyqt-tools, but now, poetry print thise error:

> Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt5-plugins (5.15.4.2.2)

my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "imageengine"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Simple image engine application for linux"
authors = ["Code Man"]
license = "GPLv3"
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.11"
pyqt5 = "5.15.4"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

my poetry info

```
Version: 1.2.2
Poetry-Core Version: 1.4.0
```

i tried found about this problem, but not founded...

```
Using version ^5.15.4.3.2 for pyqt5-tools

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.1s)

Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing pyqt5-plugins (5.15.4.2.2): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pyqt5-plugins (5.15.4.2.2)

  at /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/poetry/installation/chooser.py:103 in choose_for
       99│
      100│             links.append(link)
      101│
      102│         if not links:
    → 103│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
      104│
      105│         # Get the best link
      106│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
      107│
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include full error logs and messages

Comment: ok ) added full eror